# Nativescript 8: TNS_ENV is missing

Tags: nativescript

In older Nativescript applications development environment was checked:

```
if (TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
  // app is running in development environment
}
```

This does not work in Nativescript 8. How development environment is checked in nativescript 8?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is variable called `__DEV__` in nativescript 8.

TNS_ENV vas defined in old webpack config and webpack config has changed in nativescript 8. Docs mention [magic variables](https://docs.nativescript.org/configuration/webpack#global-magic-variables) and there is variable called `__DEV__`. New weback configuration is found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/8.1.12/packages/webpack5/src/configuration/base.ts#L387)

So in Nativescript 8 development environment is checked:

```
if (__DEV__) {
  // app is running in development environment
}
```